# JavaScript "if X" then condition content replace

Tags: javascript, if-statement, replace

im trying to edit an shop content without editing HTML (code is closed for editions, i can add only some JS or CSS. There is a div:

```
<div class="product_section" id="projector_shipping_info" style=""><label>
Ready to send</label><div><span class="projector_delivery_days" 
id="projector_delivery_days" style="display: inline;">in 21 days   </span> 
</div><a class="shipping_info" href="#shipping_info" title="Check time and price"> Check time and price</a></div>
```

Im trying to make an "if" statement to replace hard "in 21 days" shipping time, into "in 3 to 10 days". I need to use IF, cause the shipping time is one of three possible status: 21 days, 9 days and 3 days. Would love to change it for "3 to 10 days", "2-4 days" and "1-2 days".

I've tested already (and it worked out)

```
document.getElementById('projector_delivery_days').innerHTML = '';
var p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = "Shipping in 3-5 days";
document.getElementById('projector_shipping_info').appendChild(p);
```

But its static one. Wish to make an IF from this. I've tried

```
document.body.onload=function(){ var
div1=document.getElementsById('projector_delivery_days')[0];  
if(div1.innerHTML=="in 21 days   "){
document.getElementsById('projector_delivery_days')[0].innerHTML="in 3 to 10 days   ";   }    }
```

But it appears to do nothing, same goes with

```
function shipping(){
var d1 = document.getElementById('projector_delivery_days');
  if(d1.innerHTML==='in 21 days   '){
  d1.innerHTML='in 3 to 10 days   ';
  document.getElementById('projector_shipping_info').appendChild(d1);
  }
};
```

I've been struggling with this for like 2-3 days. Can someone send some help?

Comment: Instead of adding spaces in `'in 21 days   '`, use `.trim`. Also, if your purpose is to check text only, use `.innerText` instead

Answer (score 0):

The selector is `document.getElementById` not `getElementsById` . It returns the first found element with that id and not an array so no point of selecting array elements using [0]

```js
document.body.onload = function() {
  var div1 = document.getElementById('projector_delivery_days');
  if (div1.textContent == "in 21 days   ") {
    console.log(div1.textContent)
    document.getElementById('projector_delivery_days').innerHTML = "in 3 to 10 days";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="product_section" id="projector_shipping_info" style=""><label>
Ready to send</label>
  <div><span class="projector_delivery_days" id="projector_delivery_days" style="display: inline;">in 21 days   </span>
  </div><a class="shipping_info" href="#shipping_info" title="Check time and price"> Check time and price</a></div>
```

In the second snip the function is not getting called anywhere. You have to call the function on window load to replace the text

```js
window.onload=function shipping(){
var d1 = document.getElementById('projector_delivery_days');
  if(d1.innerHTML==='in 21 days   '){
  d1.textContent='in 3 to 10 days   ';
  document.getElementById('projector_shipping_info').appendChild(d1);
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="product_section" id="projector_shipping_info" style=""><label>
Ready to send</label>
  <div><span class="projector_delivery_days" id="projector_delivery_days" style="display: inline;">in 21 days   </span>
  </div><a class="shipping_info" href="#shipping_info" title="Check time and price"> Check time and price</a></div>
```

Comment: OP's second snippet shows usage of `getElementById`. Also, if this is the only issue, better mark post as typographical mistake. Also, `getElementById` is an API not selector. You pass selector to API to get element

Comment: Those still not overwriting the shop code. Is it possible to force changes? In CSS i can use !important to force my code over shops' one. Can i do simmilar with JS?

Comment: Can you please be more specific than **Those still not overwriting the shop code**

Comment: There is some kind of var in the shop code, it appears that there is "var %d" and after all it overrides everything else. Any changes to the "projector_shipping_info" ends with the same "delivery within 21days". Codes that you guys posted here - in "Run Code Snippet" works, but on webside it appears do nothing :(

Comment: I cannot see that in the snippet, can you update the question and show the exact error